# (Where) are official deprecation timelines published?

Tags: canonical, support

I was wondering **when `nftables` will become *Canonical*-supported** in Ubuntu LTS, or how much longer the `iptables` tool chain is going to remain *Canonical*-supported, assuming such change happens in some future release.

*What materials containing official deprecation timeline should I check (or re-check in the future) to figure out if such timelines are published already?*

---

What I figured out so far:

- [Searching in the package Index](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=nftables) immediately reveals the `universe` tag in all currently supported Ubuntu releases, meaning inclusion in the `main` repositories has **not yet** begun
- sometimes packages are dropped from beta shortly before release, meaning any plans for packages in future releases is **tentative** before the actual release dates

What I tried unsuccessfully:

- retrieved changelogs of [either](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/i/iptables/) [package](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/n/nftables/), nothing obvious in there
- did not find mailing list posts that announces specific plans
- not not find *Network configuration* sections in previous release notes that mention either
- [USNs](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices) only mention issues (typically issues fixed) in already released packages
- subscribe to [bugs on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nftables/+bugs), those are rarely updated when issues are addressed

Comment: 'universe' packages are supported, they are supported by the Ubuntu community and not Canonical (`ubuntu-support-status` or `ubuntu-security-status` very much favors Canonical support).  'universe' is more complex and is thus ignored by `ubuntu-security-status`, for example Ubuntu-Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release so Studio packages in 'universe' in 18.04 are already EOL; Ubuntu-Studio for documented reasons provides extended support via PPA for bionic/18.04. The best place to read is release notes (Ubuntu 18.04 release notes also note the Ubuntu Studio wasn't LTS)

Comment: I think you might be using an unusual definition of "supported". All packages in the Ubuntu repositories are *supported*, just by different groups. nftables and iptables are supported in all current releases of Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 19.10, 20.04, and both will be supported in 20.10. The Ubuntu developers have released no public discussion about replacing the default iptables with netfilter in future releases. Debian Buster has switched it's default (and instructions for users who want to switch back), but has released no plan to deprecate iptables.

Comment: @guiverc thanks, I have reworded the question. I am less concerned about years of updates promised than about packages breaking each other in unexpected ways, which generally seems to happen much less often within the `main` archives.

Comment: For a real answer, I suggest contacting the Ubuntu Foundations Team and asking them  if they have thought about such a change. Then you can answer your own question here. Best way to contact the Foundations Team is their section of http://discourse.ubuntu.com.

Comment: The example in this old question has since completed the [main inclusion process](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nftables/+bug/1887187), and [other plans](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mir) that have progressed towards initiating that process are occasionally indicative of future deprecation plans.